# How to delete an Contact in android?

Tags: android, arrays, contacts, delete-row, android-contentresolver

I have below cod and want to delete a special contact by name what i have to do?

**Note:I make a dynamic array check box for ever contact.**

Thank you in advance.

```
final Button bt2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
        {
        if(allCheckBox.get(i).isChecked() == true)
        {

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                if(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY))=="Reza")
                {
                try{
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                   Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                   System.out.println("The uri is " + uri.toString());
                    cr.delete(uri, null, null);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
                }
                }
            }

           }
        }
    }
});
```